# Reference to GeoJson object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson

**The situation**

Suppose I have two collections in my database: `cities` and `events`.

The `cities` collection stores data about world cities and each city document contain a `loc` GeoJson field like `{"type": "Point", "geometry": [lng, lat]}` so that I can query mongodb with geospatial functions like geoNear.

The `events` collection stores data about events that happen in the cities. So, each event document contain a `city` field with a reference to a city object. Using ObjectId references vs embedding city data is motivated by the fact that the number of events per city can be very large.

**The problem**

If I want geospatial data for an event I can query `events` collection and populate (using mongoose for example) the `city` field. But I cannot (I suppose) leverage mongodb geospatial functionality on `events` because they haven't a GeoJson field.

Is there something wrong with this design? I have to redesign the database or there is some mongodb (or mongoose) functionality that I don't know to  achieve this? What about best practises?

Comment: How exactly you expect to "leverage mongodb geospatial functionality"?    I am pretty sure you can combine $geoNear and $lookup in a single pipeline, but the question should have a solvable problem. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm a db beginner, the aggregation pipeline is exactly what I didn't know about mongodb.